# How to write an entry for an organization?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques

I will be running my players through a homebrew world. My players usually enjoy reading lore and quite familiar with the lore of the previous universe we played in. Though I haven't ever done this in a way that players would see(I wrote it in form of GM notes which is essentially X is evil which probably isn't appropriate for entries players would see.)

What I want to ask is how should I go at writing an entry about an organization for players to read without it being too long and giving players information they shouldn't have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What does the general public already know?

Think about some real-world organization and what we, as public people, know about them. This can help by establishing how secretive the organization might be.

Ask yourself some questions of your org. Do they do work in the open? Have they been linked to incidents or crimes? Do they call themselves the same thing that we call them? Are there any prominent or well known members?

Real-life organizations like the Church of Scientology or the Freemasons or the CIA have levels of information that the public is aware of that can be accessed on-line as well as levels of information that is completely internal and unknown to outsiders. For your organization, what would be the things that someone could find in a library book in-game about it?